# É possivel passar varaveis por parametro em javascript?

Tags: javascript

gostaria de compartilhar variaveis entre funcoes no javascript, é possivel?

funcao 1:

```
$('#btnCompra').click (function(){
 localStorage.tituloProd = 'arroz';
 tituloProd = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('tituloProd'));
 });
 });
```

funcao 2:

```
$(document).ready(function(tituloProd){
  $('.descricaoProduto').text(tituloProd);
});
```

FUNCAO JS COMPLETA:

```
var tituloProd = '?';
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#btnCompra').click (function(){

      localStorage.tituloProd = 'arroz';
      tituloProd = JSON.stringify(localStorage.getItem('tituloProd'));
    });

    $('#carrinho').click (function(){
      $('.descricaoProduto').text(tituloProd);
    });
    });
```

Comment: Weslley, se as funções estiverem no mesmo fonte, você pode declarar a variável fora das funções, isso fará com que ambas acessem a mesma variável.

Comment: Ola Daniel! Eu fiz isso, mas pelo fato de estar usando "ready function" em ambas as funçoes, o valor da variavel na segunda funcao manteve "undenified", ja que declarei ela vazia e só atribui dentro da função. Existe algum metodo que eu possa usar no ludar do "ready function"?

Comment: Editei ali, como pode ver, minha variavel 'tituloProd' foi iniciada com '?'. No primeiro metodo ela recebe um stringfy, e é esse valor que gostaria de passar pra segunda função, mas o valor que aparece é o '?' que foi declarado.

Comment: Weslley, vi que fez outra pergunta, na verdade essa rotina sofre um refesh? Seria passar esse valor entre páginas?

Comment: Oq eu quero na verdade é que quando meu cliente clicar em "adicionar carrinho" as informações como nome do produto, preço, imagem e etc, seja exibida na pagina "carrinho". Mas nao queria usar banco de dados pra isso, queria passar as variaveis através das páginas com javascript. Mas quando uso o localStorage, ele fica limitado à funcao que o criou, nao consigo enviar ele pra outra funcao

Comment: e nao sei ao certo sobre o refresh, o que eu esperava que acontecesse é que quando o cliente clicasse em "adicionar carrinho" as informações ja apareceriam na outra pagina

Comment: Normalmente vejo os sites utilizando de sessionStorage para essa parte de carrinho

Comment: A pergunta que fez não tem relação com o que você procura. Na verdade a segunda edição já resolve o problema proposto na pergunta. O que você está procurando é isso [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Comment: Nao resolve o problema, por isso mantive o topico aberto. Na primeira função a variavel recebe um valor, e na segunda função o valor que aparece é o que foi declarado ('?'), esse é o problema que estou enfrentando, o valor atribuido na primeira funcao nao aparece na segunda funçao.

Comment: Sobre a pagina: ja havia lido antes e nao solucionou o meu problema, infelizmente